# Magento 2: Can't update product stock (quantity)

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I created a console command that loops through the products and attempts to update the stock quantity. I reindex (from the command line) after it's completed but it never changes. I am on a vagrant box that has PHP7 install, and was previously getting a "Segmentation Fault" when I got to the save() method, so I had to change the indexer to "Update on Schedule" in the admin section and run the indexer from the command line manually, but I'm still not seeing the product quantity update. Is there something else I need to do in order to get the product to save properly?

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\ProductUpdate\Console\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\ConfigLoader;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class UpdateCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepo;

    /**
     * @var searchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var FilterBuilder
     */
    private $filterBuilder;

    /**
     * @var State
     */
    private $state;

    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    private $objectManager;

    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    private $registry;

    /**
     * @var ConfigLoader
     */
    private $configLoader;

    /**
     * Create new update command instance.
     *
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepo           [description]
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder      $searchCriteriaBuilder [description]
     * @param FilterBuilder              $filterBuilder         [description]
     * @param State                      $state                 [description]
     * @param ObjectManagerInterface     $objectManager         [description]
     * @param Registry                   $registry              [description]
     */
    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepo,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        State $state,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        Registry $registry,
        ConfigLoader $configLoader
    ) {
        $this->productRepo = $productRepo;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->configLoader = $configLoader;

        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('myapp:inventory:update')
            ->setDescription('Updates product quantities.');

        parent::configure();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
        $this->objectManager->configure($this->configLoader->load('adminhtml'));
        $this->registry->register('isSecureArea', true);

        $continue = true;
        $currentPage = 1;
        $currentProduct = 1;
        $perPage = 1000;

        $output->writeln('<info>Getting list of products:<info>');

        while ($continue) {
            $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
                ->setPageSize(1000)
                ->setCurrentPage(1)
                ->create();

            $results = $this->productRepo->getList($searchCriteria);

            if ($results->getTotalCount() == 0) {
                $continue = false;
                continue;
            }

            $products = $results->getItems();

            foreach ($products as $x => $product) {
                // $product->setData('qty', 100); also tried this, but it does not work.
                $product->setQty(100);
                $product->setHasDataChanges(true);

                $product->save();
                $output->writeln('<info>Updated Product: '. $product->getSku() .' | Number: ' . $currentProduct . '</info>');

                $currentProduct++;
            }

            $currentPage++;
        }

        $output->writeln('<info>Updating Complete!</info>');
    }
}
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same. Did You manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try some code like this:

```
$product->setStockData(['qty' => $qty, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);
$product->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => $qty, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);
```

it is working for me. setQty will not work since quantity is not directly stored in the product EAV table, it uses a separate stock_item table